# Execute live function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an ajax call I want to execute for 2 events, whenever the document is loaded and whenever foo-live-event is clicked. What is the best way to do this?

```
$(document).delegate(".foo-live-element", "click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    //ajax call
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo-live-element").live("click", function() {
     $.ajax({..});
  });

   /* the following code will fire the click event on all foo-live-element element's after the page loads */
   $(".foo-live-element").each(function(index, item) {
     $(item).click();
   });
});
```

this code will fire whenever an element with `class="foo-live-element"` is clicked, even if that element is created dynamically.